# Layout with caption and border, similar to the Delphi or VB.NET GroupBox

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I create a layout that has a border and a caption that is placed **on top of that border** in Android?

I'm thinking something similar to the Windows GroupBox element that is available in Delphi or VB.NET:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's late to answer but for others who have the same problem, you can use my library:

https://github.com/homayoonahmadi/GroupBoxLayout

It doesn't use any white or other color backgrounds for hiding border under the label

Answer (score -1):

in android u should use selector for radius and stroke border for specific layout

for example you should use this for border

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="12ssp"
    android:text="@string/lorem"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_item"
    android:padding="10dp" />
```

this is selector_item :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="8dp"></corners>
            <stroke android:color="@color/divider" android:width="1dp"></stroke>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

for set caption you should set a TextView bottom or above of above line border and give to that margin_bottom or margin_top

note : color of background of caption text should be exactly root layout background color

Comment: This just puts a border around the `TextView`, which is not at all what I'm asking. First, I need the view to hold child views, i.e. it should be a `ViewGroup`. Second, the caption text should be on top of the border, not inside or outside it. Otherwise it would be a trivial non-question.

Comment: For first : instead textview use a frame layout or .. for second : you can set caption on border view . Olny you should set negative margin on caption text (text view) try this . I hope useful for u :)